# Knots of fixed genus with arbitrarily large volume

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory

Consider all knots with fixed genus $g\ge 2$ (I am considering the classical 3-genus). Do there exist infinite families of genus $g$ knots with arbitrarily large volume?

The answer seems like it should definitely be yes, but I can’t seem to find any references.

Comment: What is the "3-genus"?

Comment: @IgorRivin: The usual Seifert genus (as opposed to the $4$-genus, where you allow the surface to go into the $4$-dimensional ball; thus the $4$-genus is $0$ when the knot is slice).

Comment: Is it actually clear whether there have to be infinitely many knots of a given Seifert genus?

Comment: @ThiKu: It is for except in genus $0$: just take a small band of the Seifert surface (chosen so that you aren't just pinching off a disc; this uses that the genus is at least $1$) and insert appropriate twists in it.  This doesn't change the homeomorphism type of the Seifert surface, but will give you infinitely many knots.

Comment: Please, you really should add the word "hyperbolic" (as in "hyperbolic knot" and "hyperbolic volume") in a few places in your question...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The result of Brittenham for genus 1 knots pointed out by Sam Nead was generalized to all genus in Theorem 8.2 of this paper:

*Stoimenow, A.*, [**Realizing Alexander polynomials by hyperbolic links**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.exmath.2009.06.003), Expo. Math. 28, No. 2, 133-178 (2010). [ZBL1196.57009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1196.57009).

Answer (score 8):

Here is a paper of Mark Brittenham that provides (free!) Seifert genus one  knots of arbitrarily large hyperbolic volume:

https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9809143

His construction should generalize to all genera.

Comment: Published here: https://msp.org/pjm/2001/201-1/p03.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

This question is completely answered in the paper of Purcell-Zupan and references therein.

*Purcell, Jessica S.; Zupan, Alexander*, [**Independence of volume and genus $g$ bridge numbers**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/proc/13327), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 145, No. 4, 1805-1818 (2017). [ZBL1364.57009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1364.57009).

Comment: At a cursory glance, it looks like this paper is discussing the Heegaard genus and the “bridge number” genus. I’ll take a better look in the morn.

Comment: Indeed, [PZ] is discussing a different notion of genus.  The original question should have older answers (probably even older than the one I offered below).